# Avoid non standard ASCII characters in rename command

Tags: ascii, rename, file-rename, non-ascii-characters

I am using this command to find and rename files that have non capitalised filenames in a directory (I have left the `-n` flag for safety in case anyone copies and pastes from here):

```
rename -n 's/(?<![.'\''])\b\w*/\u$&/g' *
```

The problem is that it finds files that have non standard ASCII characters such as `Noël` and regards them as a problem that would need to be fixed.

Is there any way to avoid that happening?

---

Edit (20180701-1635):

I just realised that the command also 'fails' (tries to rename) if a filename contains a dash or an apostrophe too (it changes the character following to uppercase).  Examples of wrong renames currently:

Alan's Filename.txt > Alan'S Filename.txt

File-name.txt > File-Name.txt

---

Comment: Can you replace `\w` with `[[:alpha:]]`?

Comment: `rename != rename`. What I mean is that there are different versions of the `rename` command available, all come with a different set of options and features. Some do not support regexes at all. Which version of rename are you using?

Comment: @ Benjamin W:  I tried this (exactly as shown here) but without the <> around it:   <rename -n 's/(?<![.'\''])\b[[:alpha:]]*/\u$&/g' *> It still wants to rename  Noël to  NoëL (ie it wants to replace the lowercase 'el' after the French 'ë' with an uppercase 'el').  Alan.

Comment: @hek2mgl:  /usr/bin/rename using File::Rename version 0.20

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit diffuse but I think you mean something like:

```
for i in $(echo * | sed 's, YOUR_REG_EGP ,,g'); do
  # your rename commmands on $i
done
```

Comment: I'll try to be less gaseous :-)  Does that mean I would use:
  for i in $(echo * | sed 's/(?<![.'\''])\b\w*/\u$&/g'); do
  rename -n 's/(?<![.'\''])\b\w*/\u$&/g' *
done